# How to splice 2 mx canvas objects with repeat-x backgrounds?

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, user-interface, flex3

I have 2 canvas objects that both contain a tiling image. My client recently requested that both the images be able to appear at the same time. I simply allowed them to be both enabled at the same time thinking they would tile appropriately but they do not.

After some careful thought I realized this is because they are of varying width so although my tiling image is 7 pixels in width, it may not always end at 7 pixels thus causing it to not appear to tile cleanly.

I can't just lop off the remainders because the imagery is being used to assess quantities of items (without going into too much detail) and having item 1 with 97 quantity next to item 2 with 200 quantity on one row compared to row 2 with item 1 having 100 quantity and item 2 having 300 quantity will show up strange to the end-user.

Does anyone know of how I could get started with maybe splicing the two canvas objects together or rather using 1 canvas object and then using BOTH background images and setting a percentWidth or something that the other one comes into affect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I was overcomplicating it. I simply did this with masking like...

```
<mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:Image id="myFirstUnrelatedImage" width="50%" height="65%" maintainAspectRatio="false"
              verticalCenter="0" left="3"
              source="@Embed('../assets/image1.png')" visible="true"/>

    <!-- not sure why borderStyle here is required but it won't show up without? -->
    <mx:Canvas id="image1mask" width="30%" height="94%" 
               borderStyle="none" visible="false"/> 
    <mx:Canvas id="image1" width="100%" height="100%"
               minWidth="0" styleName="myStyle"
               mask="{image1mask}"/>

    <!-- not sure why borderStyle here is required but it won't show up without? -->
    <mx:Canvas id="image2mask" width="20%" height="94%"
               right="0" borderStyle="none" visible="false"
               includeInLayout="false"/> 
    <mx:Canvas id="image2" width="100%" height="100%"
               minWidth="0" styleName="myStyle2"
               mask="{image2mask}"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Where my styles were controlling the backgroundImage and backgroundRepeat properties in css.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [copyPixels()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29) method of the BitmapData class to achieve this sort of result. To do this, you need to load each image with a `Loader`. When the images are loaded, you have two `Bitmap` objects. From there, you access the corresponding `BitmapData` for each `Bitmap` and can splice them together.

After the splice, you create a new `Bitmap` object from the combined `BitmapData`. Then you feed the combined `Bitmap` to some other component. Unfortunately, a `Canvas` won't accept a `Bitmap` for its `backgroundImage` style. But you can add the combined `Bitmap` to a `UIComponent` or set it as the `source` of an `Image` component.

Finally, add either the `UIComponent` or `Image` to a `Canvas`. Since you can layer things on the `Canvas`, you effectively have a background image as long as place (and leave) the combined image at index 0 of the `Canvas`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                layout="vertical"
                minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
                creationComplete="onCreationComplete()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.containers.Canvas;
            import mx.controls.Image;
            import mx.core.UIComponent;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private var loader1:Loader;
            private var loader2:Loader;
            private var bitmap1:BitmapData;
            private var bitmap2:BitmapData;

            protected function onCreationComplete():void
            {
                loader1 = new Loader();
                loader1.load(new URLRequest("Android_Robot_100.png"));
                loader1.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoader1Complete, false,0,true);
                loader2 = new Loader();
                loader2.load(new URLRequest("rails.png"));
                loader2.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoader2Complete, false,0,true);
            }

            protected function onLoader1Complete(event:Event):void
            {
                bitmap1 = (loader1.content as Bitmap).bitmapData;
                if (bitmap1 && bitmap2)
                    copyPixels();
            }

            private function onLoader2Complete(event:Event):void
            {
                bitmap2 = (loader2.content as Bitmap).bitmapData;
                if (bitmap1 && bitmap2)
                    copyPixels();
            }

            protected function copyPixels():void
            {
                // false = non-transparent background
                var combined:BitmapData = new BitmapData(200,200, false);
                var sourceRect1:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,bitmap1.width, bitmap1.height);
                var sourceRect2:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,bitmap2.width, bitmap2.height);
                combined.copyPixels(bitmap1, sourceRect1, new Point(0,0));
                combined.copyPixels(bitmap2, sourceRect2, new Point(bitmap1.width, 0));
                var result:Bitmap = new Bitmap(combined);
                var image:Image = new Image();
                image.source = result;
                var canvas:Canvas = new Canvas();
                canvas.addChildAt(image, 0);
                addChild(canvas);
                // as an alternative, just add the bitmap to a UIComponent
                // note you can't do this and the above at the same time,
                // becuase the 'result` Bitmap can only be the child of one
                // object, adding it to one thing removes it from the other...
//              var uic:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
//              uic.addChild(result);
//              addChild(uic);
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Not sure if this works because I haven't tested it but I found an easy solution, please see my answer if you're interested.

Comment: It works :) because I wrote a complete application that proves it. Glad you found your own solution!